# How to create a custom webhook in Dialogflow based on Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, dialogflow-es

So I would like to implement Dialogflow fulfilliment using a custom node.js webhook. I've created a node.js app in Azure (I have my own .azurewebsites.net site), however I'm not quite sure how to link it to Dialogflow. How do I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On the dialog flow side Go to dashboard and click on fulfillment on side bar provide the web hook and basic authentication and headers. 
On nodeJs make sure you provide POST Webhook API where dialogflow app sends requests.

Comment: Sorry I should have made the question more clear. The first part is easy and I've had it set up for a while, but I dont understand how to provide a POST Webhook API in node.js.

Comment: Use Express REST API to make endpoint on nodejs. You can follow the reference. https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with Express or any other framework to create REST APIs with Node?

There are tons of material on the web, but this is a [starting point](https://medium.com/@purposenigeria/build-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-express-js-d7e59c7a3dfb) if you like.

In [this link](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/how-it-works) you'll find the documentation that shows which fields will be posted to your endpoint and those that you'll want to send back to Dialogflow.